# is there a way to combine xpath and regexp to extract parts of a node value?

Tags: java, regex, xpath

this is what I want...

Assuming I'm trying to get at the value of 'B'

```
<tree>
<nodea>
<nodeb>
A=foo;
B=bar;
C=goo;
</nodeb>
</nodea>
</tree>
```

the following is magical syntax which would make sense... I'm looking for something comparable that actually works :)

```
string = "./nodea/nodeb/[ REGEX( 'B=(.*?);' ) ]/ $1"
```

Is there anything like this in any java xpath library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[XPath 2.0 adds regular expressions](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#regex-syntax). Something like this ought to do what you want, I think:

```
fn:replace(./nodea/nodeb, ".*B=(.*?);.*", "$1")
```

Comment: I believe you're right! (though in the interest of someone finding this and trying to use it in the future, please edit your answer and replace your regexp with this...
".*?B=(.*?);.*"  otherwise the thing get hungry and skips all the valuable bits :)

Comment: which library should I be using? it seems that the javax library doesn't know what to do with an xpath string that starts with "fn:replace("

Comment: Looks like no version of Java comes with XPath 2.0. :( I believe you'll need to use Saxon.